# Retrieve schema of User Defined Table Type from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema

I am wondering if there is a way in C# to retrieve the schema of a User-Defined Table Type from a SQL database instance. I see that the `DbConnection` class provides a `GetSchema()` method for getting table schema information, but I have not been able to figure out a way to get schema information for a User-Defined Table Type. What I am interested in retrieving is the name of the type, and information about the columns like data type, nullable, name, etc. Does anyone have experience doing this? Thanks!

NOTE: This question is NOT asking how to pass a User-Defined Table Type as a parameter to a stored procedure from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SMO. I'm just a DBA, so Powershell is my tool of choice, but the concepts should be immediately transferable:

```
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
$db = $s.databases['myDatabase'];

$db.UserDefinedTableTypes | select schema, name;
```

Once you have a UserDefinedTableType SMO object, you can get use the Columns method on a given type, which will return a collection of Column objects. Each of those will have all the relevant information for the columns (name, type, nullability, etc)

Comment: Interesting. I think this Powershell is using some .NET libraries under the hood, so perhaps I can try to reference that library and see what it offers. I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: Absolutely it is. The namespace is SMO (referenced in the new-object line).

Comment: This worked great! I needed to reference three of the SQL Server assemblies: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, and Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo. I am now able to get all of the metadata I needed.

Comment: so what is the final solution? I am also trying to create datatable on the fly. to not duplicate structure on c# part. Which libraries should I add and how some sample fragment will look like?

Comment: @Yauhen.F: You're not asking the same question, so providing the answer here isn't the best for people in the future looking to solve the same problem. Submit a new question and I'm sure it will be answered (by me or someone else). Also, be prepared to show what you've tried… questions phrased as "solve my problem for me" don't tend to go over well here.

Comment: but I have 90% the same question. why should I produce duplicates? I need to read user defined table type structure from c#. preferrably without additional procedures. I have just typed title and it is suggested this post. This solution sounds good but not fully described how to make it working on c#

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution. But this will work. Assuming your used defined table type name is "UDT_Sample"

```
DECLARE @UDT UDT_Sample
SELECT * INTO tempUDT FROM @UDT
EXECUTE sp_columns 'tempUDT'
DROP TABLE tempUDT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the procedure

sp_columns 'TableName'

to get the schema information in SqlServer.

Comment: I am aware of how to get the schema information via SQL, but I was curious if there was a way to get the schema from C# (without having C# calling a stored procedure). For example, I know that the Entity Framework database first is able to get a lot of schema information from a database without having to call a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            UserDefinedSchemaTable = connection.GetSchema("StructuredTypeMembers", new string[] { null, null, null,null });
        }
```

Comment: could you please explain what is going on in your code?  it may be obvious to you and other experienced programmers, but when you add some explanation it makes the answer that much better and ultimately leads to more upvotes.